# Confusion about filter transfer function

Tags: filter, low-pass, transfer-function

Today I got confused about Low pass filter transfer function.
Let's assume we have a simple low pass RC filter . It is well known that at f=fc we expect -3dB (0.707) drop in Vin.

Everyone knows a LPF transfer function is:

[image]

On the other hand we know that :

[image]

Which results in :

[image]

If we set f=fc  we will have:

[image]

But I expected 1/√2 =0.707  !  I am sure I am missing something but can not find that because this differs from the formula that I knew:

[image].

Comment: Your result is correct *if* the input to the filter is \$e^{t/RC}\$, a *real* exponential.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has come from the substitution of s for 2*PI*f.

s is a substitution for j*w

thus the equation actually is:   1/(1+j)
If you resolve this back to magnitude:   1+j = sqrt(1^2 + 1^2)  = sqrt(2)

resulting in:  1/sqrt(2)  = 0.707
as you expect

So take a low-pass filter: RC

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffj0NR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$
Vout = Vin*\frac{\frac{1}{j\omega C}}{R + \frac{1}{j\omega C}}
$$
$$
Vout = Vin*\frac{1}{j\omega RC + 1}
$$
$$
\frac{Vout}{Vin} = \frac{1}{j\omega RC + 1}
$$
$$
\frac{Vout}{Vin} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(\omega RC)^{2} + 1^{2}}}
$$
From a magnitude point of view.

Comment: I thought s=j*w*f not j*w. Is that?

Comment: w (radians per second)  is equal to 2*pi*f